# How do I write automated tests in Selenium for Google OneTap now that the dialog is browser native in FedCM?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, google-one-tap, fedcm

Since migrating to FedCM, I’m not sure how to write automated tests in Selenium (Java) given that the UI is now browser native (not in the DOM) and some critical displayMoment notifications have been deprecated.

How can I interact with the dialog?

I expected some way to interact with the auth process, but there doesn’t appear to be a way to detect or interact with the native browser UI.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this area, but Selenium does have a plan to support FedCM https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/13449
Chrome supports it already https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/rsBIIyLnLeA